# python append to nested list , index out of range

Tags: python, list, nested

I am trying to create a nested list. The result would be something like `[[0,1],[2,3],[0,4]]` I tried the following and got an index out of range error:

```
list = []
list[0].append(0)
```

Is it not appending 0 to the first item in the list? How should I do this? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: *"Is it not appending 0 to the first item in the list?"* What first item in the list? That list is empty.

Comment: I must notice that shadowing built-in name `list` with `list = []` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little typo, you should do:

```
list = [[]]
list[0].append(0)
```

You need to *have* a first element first...

**Edit:**

Use:

```
list = []
for i in range(3):
    list.append([])
    list[-1].append(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. But if it is in a loop, how do I initialise the n item before append?

Comment: @user4046073 Edited mine,

Answer (score 1):

For that you'll need to append a `list` to a `list` first, i.e.:

```
list = []
list.append([])
list[0].append(0)
print(list)
# [[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = []
lst.append([0,1])
lst.append([2,3])
lst.append([0,4])
print(lst)
```

How about this ? Or you need in the form of loop with constant set of numbers?